# Install custom Outlook 2003 form in user's Personal Form Library

Tags: outlook, ms-office, vsto

We've developed a custom Outlook 2003 form based on ipmNote. I need a way to push this to all the other users in the organization. At the same time we'll also be installing a custom Add-in built with VSTO so we could do the form install as part of that.

Currently I can't use the Organizational Forms Library, because the exchange admins don't want to turn on public folders.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to appear in the user's Personal Form Library?  If it's being published to everyone in the company, you would normally publish it to the Organisational Forms Library on the Exchange Server.

When your users opened the form for the first time, it would be pulled down to their local machine and stored in an application folder within their Documents and Settings.

Have a look at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=34 for some helpful information